# Is there a difference between href='image/{{$image->id}}' and href='/image/{{$image->id}}'?

Tags: php, laravel

This piece of code is part of my index/home page on `localhost:8088` URL, if I want to send the user to url localhost:8088/image/1, do I write `href='image/{{$image->id}}'` or `href='/image/{{$image->id}}'` and is there a difference between the 2?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    @foreach($images as $image)
    <div class='imageContainer'>
        <a class='stickyImageContainer homePage' href='image/{{$image->id}}'>
            <h1 class='imageTitle'>{{$image->name}}</h1>
            <img class='uploadedImg' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
        </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the form

```
href='/image/{{$image->id}}'
```

This is less to do with PHP and Laravel, and more to do with the HTML you're using PHP and Laravel to generate.  In HTML, when you use an absolute URL

```
/this/is/a/absolute/url
```

The browser will append your absolute URL to the current domain name, and that's where a user will be sent. However, if you're using a relative url

```
this/is/a/relative/url
```

Then the browser will look at the current URL of the page you're on, and append your relative URL to that (minus any file name).

So in your case, both links would work is the URL was

```
http://example.com
```

However, if the URL was

```
http://example.com/foo/bar.html
```

Then your first (absolute) example would send you to

```
http://example.com/image/102
```

and the second (relative) example would send you to

```
http://example.com/foo/image/102
```

Comment: Does it make sense to use href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}' ?

Comment: As it's not my application, I don't know if it makes sense, but using the url helper function will generate a link that includes a fully qualified http or https domain name in your link.  This is probably OK, unless you've got some weird multiple domain name thing going on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url